# App crash when run Unity Vuforia in Iphone, iPad with multiple Image Target

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I use Vuforia library to detect Area Target and two Image targets. when I put that two image target in front of camera and Vuforia **can detect single image**, it can not detect both in one time.
So I change the **Max Simultaneous Tracked Images** in ARCamera inspector from 1 to 2,in computer(MacOS) it can detect both and No memory leak. But if I build unity to iPhone or iPad, devices will crash after vuforia detect image (unity work well in these device when Max Simultaneous Tracked Images = 1). [Vuforia ARCamera Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQHxV.png)
An Hieracht [Hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ac3w.png)

Try to change **Max Simultaneous Tracked Images**

Comment: Are you using the “development build” in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug. I would file an issue in vuforia-engine issue repository here https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine